# Potential function & constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

$\mathbf{Question:}$

Give a piar functions $Φ:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $ and $Ψ: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, it is often useful to known that there exists some contiunously differentiable function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ such that $\partial f/\partial x(x,y)=Φ(x,y)$ and $\partial f/\partial y(x,y)=Ψ(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$

Such a function $f$ is called a potential function for the pair of functions $(Φ,Ψ)$

$\mathbf{part \ a)}$ show that if a potential function exists then this potential is uniquely determined up to an additive constant - that is, the difference of any two potential is constant.

---

I guess, I need to use the definition of continuously differentiablity. But how?

Please show me a way. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are two potential functions for the vector field $(\Phi,\Psi)$. Then the gradient of $f-g$ is identically zero. What do you know about functions with vanishing gradient (on pathwise connected sets)?

---

If you don't know any such suitable theorem, try taking an arbitrary parametrized curve $\gamma(t)$, and look at $h(t) = f(\gamma(t)) - g(\gamma(t))$.

Comment: Now, step by step I am asking to you and replying your questions:)

Comment: Since $\nabla (f-g)=\nabla f -\nabla g= \partial f/\partial x + \partial f/\partial y -\partial g/\partial x - \parital g/\partial y= Φ(x,y)+Ψ(x,y)-Φ(x,y)-Ψ(x,y)=0$

Comment: Is this right? @mrf ?

Comment: So far, so good.

Comment: Well, but I dont understand your question? I am looking at the book. But I dont find such a theorem:(

Comment: What's the corresponding result for functions of one variable? (What can you say about a function whose derivative is zero everywhere?)

Comment: If the derivatives of a function is zero everywhere, then it is constant function of course. Oh okay I understand well:)